# Implementation of if_nametoindex

Tags: c, macos, network-programming, kernel, bsd

Where can I find the implementation of if_nametoindex? It seems to be externed in net/if.h but searching through the source code I cannot find any hint on the implementation. A better question is, how would I find what library it is defined in etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to search through all projects, not just apple sources: http://code.metager.de/source/s?&sort=relevancy&defs=if_nametoindex&reset=true

Take a look at [freebsd implementation](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/freebsd/lib/libc/net/if_nametoindex.c#64) for example.